# Is there a way to prevent Python from recognizing escape characters?

Tags: python

Code:

```
import os
filename = "cp.lnk"
lnk = "shortcuts\cmd_shortcuts\" + filename
os.system(lnk)
```

And that gives me this error, I'm assuming, because it recognizes escape quotes in the variable:

> 'shortcuts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I then tried:

```
import os
filename = "cp.lnk"
lnk = r"shortcuts\cmd_shortcuts\" + filename
os.system(lnk)
```

It game me the same error. How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Edit: Sorry my question was so bad ):

Comment: It would help if you posted the error as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the **full text** of the error or traceback as formatted text, not an image.

Comment: If this is Windows note that forward slashes work as well.

Comment: _SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal_: please provide a [mre], the issue doesn't even seem related to file path

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: The problem with `r` strings is they can't end with a backslash.  And I don't think your second example gives the *same* error as the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that should fix it but don't quote me on that.

```
import os
filename = "cp.lnk"
lnk = r"shortcuts\\cmd_shortcuts\\" + filename
os.system(lnk)
```

```
import os
filename = "cp.lnk"
lnk = "shortcuts\\cmd_shortcuts\\" + filename
os.system(lnk)
```